# Writing a JSON of different types in Go (int and string)

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I'm new to Go and Json, so I might miss a lot of points here.

So what I'm basically trying to do is making a program which performs the simple [Fizz-Buzz program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) and make a JSON out of it.
This program takes two integers (*a* and *b*), iterate from *a* to *b* (*i*) and outputs:

- "Fizz" if the number is a factor of 3
- "Buzz" if the number is a factor of 5
- "FizzBuzz" if the number is a factor both and,
- *i* if the number isn't a factor of both

Using this simple code snippet:

```
func fizzbuzz(a int, b int) string{
    str := fmt.Sprint("{\"output\":[")
    for i := a ; i <= b; i++ {
        if i%5 == 0 && i%3 == 0 {str = fmt.Sprint(str, "\"FizzBuzz\"")
        }else if i%3 == 0 {str = fmt.Sprint(str, "\"Fizz\"")
        }else if i%5 == 0 {str = fmt.Sprint(str, "\"Buzz\"")
        }else {str = fmt.Sprint(str, i)}
        str = str + ","
    }
    str = str[:len(str) - 1]
    str = str + "]}"
    return str
}
```

I was able to construct the string that can later on be converted to JSON:

```
{"output":["FizzBuzz",1,2,"Fizz",4,"Buzz","Fizz",7,8,"Fizz","Buzz",11,"Fizz",13,14,"FizzBuzz"]}
```

This works fine so far. I'm just wondering, are there any other solutions to making a JSON array of mixed type (integer and strings) on Golang? I've tried struct and [marshaling](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json), but a struct seems to have fixed structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two good options that come to mind.

You can use an interface type.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
)

type output struct {
    Output []interface{} `json:"output"`
}

func main() {
    out := output{
        Output: []interface{}{"FizzBuzz", 1, 2, "Fizz"},
    }
    d, _ := json.Marshal(out)
    os.Stdout.Write(d)
}
```

Output:

```json
{"output":["FizzBuzz",1,2,"Fizz"]}
```

Or you can use a different JSON library, like gojay, which has a different API for serializing JSON.

Comment: I was thinking of the interface route as well https://play.golang.org/p/bhqGdSEL2h6